# Can the validity start date of my UK visitor visa be changed to an earlier date?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, legal, standard-visitor-visas

I got my standard visitor visa for UK stamped and it starts from 15th April. But my flight will be reaching London on 14th April 7AM local time(due to my mistake of overlooking dates).
I think airline will not allow me to board.
I am currently in USA and am a permanent resident of USA with an Indian nationality.
 Can I apply for change in dates to start a day early  or apply for a new visa? What are my options?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean British consulate in New York? Their website clearly says they do not entertain visa related enquiries.

Comment: You're quite right. This is a bit beyond my knowledge. But I am sure that someone will be along with an answer shortly.

Comment: When did you receive the confirmation email? And/or get your stuff back from the VFS/post?

Comment: I got my passport today morning. Confirmation email came last Friday i.e. 18th march.

Comment: How about changing your date of travel to next day? Hassle free option if your schedule permits.

Comment: They are not going to be accommodating about it because your passport has been returned and they told you not to purchase tickets in advance.  The path of least resistance is to rebook the flight, otherwise you can make a new application or send your stuff back and ask for discretionary relief from the fee.  When that happens they will put a cancelled no prejudice stamp on your visa which is not bad but totally spoils the optics. Rebook the flight.

Comment: @jamessug IMHO not a duplicate as this questions asks to change the validity start date of a visa.

Comment: @joe The question might not be a duplicate but the question is answered in the proposed dupe, right? _" ... if the start date they give is wrong for you then you can return your passport and request another start date._

Comment: @jamessug Yes but if I recall correctly duplicates are for questions, not answers.

Comment: @joe Hmm. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/260340 suggests that it's based on answers, not questions. _"This includes not only word-for-word duplicates, but also the same idea expressed in different words."_

Comment: @JoErNanO Looks pretty similar to me - it's about someone wanting to travel a day or two before the date on their visa

Comment: @JoErNanO that's if THEY give the wrong date, not the end-user.  And also, the duplicate text says "...has an answer...", it does not require the question to be a duplicate, read it.

Comment: For who is following the argument about duplication in this comments, there are related posts in chat and for duplicate policy referring to the following TSE meta posts http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/1525/32134 and http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/698/32134 as well as an SO blog on the topic http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Comment: I am going to do re-apply. Rebooking the flight is much much costlier than application fee. So it makes sense to go for reapply.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems reapplying is one option. Since rebooking the flight is much costlier than reapplying , I am going to reapply.

EDIT :-
I reapplied following exactly same procedure as I did the first time. Got a call from British Consulate , NY as to why I am applying again when I already have visa. I explained the reason and that person was okay with that. Got approval email a couple of hours later. My UPS package has already started from there and should be here tomorrow morning.

In the end, saved more than a grand! It was worth the effort.

Comment: Did anyone downvote this? May I know why? Is this not a good thing to do?

Comment: I didnt downvote. But curious to know as you have decided to reapply for visa, you will not be able to travel on the current ticket so eventually you will have to rebook the flight right. Is that not costlier too :P

Comment: I reapplied to align with flight dates.